# SQL -Query to find specific column in all the tables of the database but having no null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am not an SQL Expertise. I need to search for the column which is present in all the tables of the database but which does not has null values stored for that specific record.

Below is the query that fetches me all the tables that has my column name:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE 'classPK'
```

Comment: Relevant: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/in-sql-server-2008-how-can-i-get-all-the-columns-that-are-marked-as-nullable-in

Comment: The question is rather: Why do you need to search those tables? Why the same column name in several tables? BTW; LIKE without wildcards makes no sense, do "WHERE column_name = 'classPK'" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
declare @q nvarchar(1000);
declare cur_Select cursor for 
select  'select * from ['+tab.name+'] where ['+col.name+'] is not null'
from    sys.tables tab
join    sys.columns col
    on  tab.object_id = col.object_id
where col.name like 'name'

open cur_Select
fetch next from cur_Select into @q

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    exec sp_executesql @q   

    fetch next from cur_Select into @q

end

close cur_Select
deallocate cur_Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this statement:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @crs CURSOR;
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

  set @crs = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE column_name LIKE 'CD_CIC_PROD%'


    BEGIN TRY
          OPEN @crs
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM @crs INTO
            @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME   

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        set @query = 'SELECT * FROM  ['+@TABLE_NAME+'] WHERE ['+@COLUMN_NAME+'] IS NOT NULL'

        EXEC sp_executesql @query

        FETCH NEXT FROM @crs INTO
            @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME   

    END
```